# Is file reading faster in nested folders or doesn't matter?

Tags: python, directory, lookup, filepath, disk

My question concerns purely file-path reading and Disk Drives...I think.

I have python code that needs to pull up a specific file of which I know exactly the file-path to. And I have a choice either I store that file in a large folder with thousands of other files or segment them all into sub-folders. Which choice would give more reading speed?

My concern and lack of knowledge suggests that when code enters a big folder with thousands of other files then that is much more of a struggle than entering a folder with a few sub-folders. Or am I wrong and it is all instant if I produce the exact file-path?

Again I don't have to scan the files or folders as I know exactly the file-path link but I don't know what happens on the lower-level with Disk Drives?

EDIT: **Which of the two would be faster given standard HDD on Windows 7?**

> C://Folder_with_millions_of_files/myfile.txt

or

> C://small_folder/small_folder254/small_folder323/myfile.txt

NOTE: What I need this for is not to scan thousands of files but to pull up just that one file as quickly as possible. Sort of a lookup table I think this is.

Comment: I do not know enough to answer the question but I would have thought it would make no difference at a python level and this would instead heavily depend on the file system, caching and hardware of the machine behind this. If you have an easy method to separate the files like categories that is the way I would go should you ever need to list them out.

Comment: Welcome to SO in order to ask questions you should review the following https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
                                                                              
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes indeed this is a File System issue I am asking. I am mentioning the python code for context. I have just a standard laptop with HDD, Windows 7. And I have stumbled wondering if I should store my files in sub-folders or does it not even matter if I produce the exact filepath.


Example, do I choose: 

C://FolderWithMillionFiles/myfile.txt

or

C://Folder1/Folder2/FolderWithTenFiles/myfile.txt

Comment: @tribunalstorm You could try it out and then add the results here. Maybe that will help answer your question.

Comment: I will post here if I do try it out, but because of how large the files are it is very difficult for me to test this out which is why I wanted to do it correctly in the first place and hoped someone knows an easy answer! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some reading for maximum scalability it appears best practice is to split the folder to subfolders although you nesting multiple folders is not recomended and it is best to use multiple larger folders than thousands of smaller folders,

> Rather than shoveling all of those files into a single filesystem, why not spread them out across a series of smaller filesystems? The problems with that approach are that (1) it limits the kernel's ability to optimize head seeks and such, reducing performance, and (2) it forces developers (or administrators) to deal with the hassles involved in actually distributing the files. Inevitably things will get out of balance, forcing things to be redistributed in the future.

From looking at these articles I would draw the following conclusion, 
< 65,534 files (One folder should suffice) 
> 65,534 files (Split into folders)

To allow for scalability in the future it would be advisable to split the data across folders but based on the file system and observed performance potentially creating a new folder per 65,534 items or per day, category etc.

Based on, 
[single folder or many folders for storing 8 million images of hundreds of stores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496452/single-folder-or-many-folders-for-storing-8-million-images-of-hundreds-of-stores) 
https://lwn.net/Articles/400629/ 
https://superuser.com/questions/446282/max-files-per-directory-on-ntfs-vol-vs-fat32

Comment: Thank you for answer and those reference links as well, really helped to clear some things up.